# How to create a datagrid with wav-files in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding, wav

I hope somebody could help me. I want to add a wav-file for every object in my objectlist. The class is bound to an ObservableCollection. But I want to know the easiest way to read and play these wav-files from a datagrid using SoundPlayer?

```
public string CoName
{
   get { return coName; }
   set 
   { 
         coName = value;
         Changed("CoName");
   }
}

public byte[] CoSound
{
   get { return coSound; }
   set 
   { 
         coSound = value;
         Changed("CoSound");
   }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to play the sound? when user clicks a cell on DataGrid?

Comment: I want to play the sound with a MouseOverEvent, because in the datagrid there are some coordinates for rectangles, drawn on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

You should bind the Source property of MediaElement to the wav file (CoSound?).

You should also define the style of the datagrid so that the column you want to put the sound on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. My problem is to handle appending audio-files, reading and storing it to my objectlist. Therefore I have  to call an OpenFileDialog and ReadAllBytes to a buffer? Am I right?

Comment: If you have the path to the files you can just set it as the value of the source property. The control will do the rest. If you have a dynamic number of files you can set a folder where the files are get all the audio-files on it and add to your ObservableCollection.

Comment: If you need a guide on binding and templating you can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx